Understanding when a compiler copies, moves or constructs in place
I've been reading up on copy and move semantics to improve my knowledge of when to use T vs T const & vs T &&
I wrote a small bit of test code to verify my intuition
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

template< int i >
struct Example
{
    Example(){ std::cout << "("<< i<<") was made\n"; }
    Example( Example const & ){ std::cout << "("<< i<<") was copied\n"; }
    Example( Example && ){ std::cout << "("<< i<<") was moved\n"; }
    ~Example(){ std::cout << "("<< i<<") was destroyed\n"; }
    
    std::vector< int > x = {1,2,3,4};
};

template< int i >
struct Test
{
    Example< i > example;
    
    // Test( Example< i > example ): example( example ) {}
    
    // Test( Example< i > const & example ): example( example ) {}
    // Test( Example< i > && example ): example( std::move(example) ) {}
};

int main()
{
    Example<1> example1;
    Example<2> example2;
    
    std::cout << "Test1\n";
    Test test1{ example1 };
    std::cout << "Test2\n";
    Test test2{ std::move(example2) };
    std::cout << "Test3\n";
    Test test3{ Example<3>() };
    
    std::cout << "Tests done \n";
}

This produces the output I expect:
(1) was made
(2) was made
Test1
(1) was copied
Test2
(2) was moved
Test3
(3) was made
Tests done 
(3) was destroyed
(2) was destroyed
(1) was destroyed
(2) was destroyed
(1) was destroyed

g++ -std=c++20 -O3
Adding explicit constructor to Test
    Test( Example< i > const & example ): example( example ) {}
    Test( Example< i > && example ): example( std::move( example ) ) {}

Still fits my intuition, as now that there is only a copy and move, test3 now resorts to using a move.
However when only defining the following constructor
    Test( Example< i > example ): example( example ) {}

I get
(1) was made
(2) was made
Test1
(1) was copied
(1) was copied
(1) was destroyed
Test2
(2) was moved
(2) was copied
(2) was destroyed
Test3
(3) was made
(3) was copied
(3) was destroyed
Tests done 
(3) was destroyed
(2) was destroyed
(1) was destroyed
(2) was destroyed
(1) was destroyed

Whilst I can understand the extra copy of example1, it still seems strange to me. However it does not make sense in combination with what happends to example3 I would either also expect two copies or a move.
I was always under the impression that:

You pass by value if you plan on taking a copy of a resource, and if a temporary is passed to this function, that the compiler can use a move instead or even construct the object in place
You pass by lvalue reference, if you plan only viewing the object (const &) or if you plan on setting the value.
You pass by rvalue reference, if you plan on taking ownership of an resource.

Put with this example this does not seem the case, as given in the example Example contains a vector, thus a copy is not the lightest operation there is and a move would be prefereable.
So my question summarized is:
To avoid expensive copies and to allow for constructing in place, when should you use T, T&, T const & and T&& ( maybe T const && ).
This is also in the context of functions not just constructors.
( Note: with construct in place I mean the phenomina as shown for test3 initialy where the temporary object is neither moved or copied into test3 )

"when should you use T, T&, T const & and T&& ( maybe T const && )..." See this answer. Also const T& vs. T&& and also Whether to use T const& or T&&

@user12002570 I do not believe this is a full duplicate. As these questions do not address the difference between passing by value and reference. Nor do they talk about when a compiler can construct in place.

Passing by value and reference is Difference between passing by value and reference which is language-agnostic.

"To avoid expensive copies and to allow for constructing in place, when should you use T, T&, T const & and T&& ( maybe T const && )...." Passing by reference by definition means you want to avoid a copy.

I've reopened. Although I do think it is somewhat unclear. Are you also asknig for the explanation of why you got the output in the second version in addition to asking "To avoid expensive copies and to allow for constructing in place, when should you use T, T&, T const & and T&& ( maybe T const && )."

@SamCoutteau -- Instead of just printing (1), (2), etc.  you should be outputing the value of this so you know exactly which object(s) are being created, copied, and destroyed.

just for the record: Nothing is actually being moved in your code. The compiler generated move constructor for Example would, but yours just leaves the member to be default initialized.

This question is too broad. Each part of the question is answered in other questions, e.g. "maybe T const &&": Do rvalue references to const have any use?. Your question is not a duplicate of one other question, because other questions are more focused.

https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#fcall-parameter-passing

In short, prefer reference T&, unless the type is small, like int. If the type is not going to be used by the caller code, consider T&& + std::move().
The simplicity of the code is more important that speed, unless you measure that this is a hot spot of your program.
C++ Core guidelines that you linked in the comment: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#fcall-parameter-passing
